# Remove a node from a recursive JSON

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recursion

Below is my recursive structure and I need to remove any node whose id is a match. I have been struggling to get this exactly right for my `deleteNode(explorerData, itemId, isFolder)` function.

This should return me a tree which has the node deleted. Here's the [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/file-explorer-muecly?file=/src/App.js:599-761) to CodeSandbox, if needed, but this is not required really

```
const explorer = {
  id: "1",
  name: "root",
  isFolder: "true",
  items: [
    {
      id: "2",
      name: "public",
      isFolder: "true",
      items: [
        { id: "3", name: "index.html", isFolder: false, items: [] },
        { id: "4", name: "style.css", isFolder: false, items: [] }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: "5",
      name: "app.js",
      isFolder: false,
      items: []
    },
    {
      id: "6",
      name: "src",
      isFolder: true,
      items: [
        {
          id: "7",
          name: "components",
          isFolder: true,
          items: [
            {
              id: "8",
              name: "Folder.js",
              isFolder: false,
              items: []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Took a break and came up with what was required at first place. I got confused to think of return `{}` empty object initially when I was doing it this way. To counter this empty object I had messed my thought process. However, simple check of empty objects on UI component saves my day, I don't have to render it on screen if the object is empty. This is also the correct approach to render.  I agree, that there is one object iteration in data structure for empty object but hey, we are only gonna delete a few times. Even when we do say 10 times, the server call must have saved this results and backend can filter this for empty objects while storing. What comes back later is just filled objects.

```
function deleteNode(tree, itemId) {
    if (tree.id === itemId) {
      return {};
    }
    const children = tree.items.map((obj) => {
      return deleteNode(obj, itemId);
    });
    return { ...tree, items: children };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A little complex but optimised logic:

- Check if Object or sub-tree has searched item

  - If no, continue.
  - If yes, check current object.

    - If yes, return `null`
    - Else return object
  - If its not the object, loop through items.

    - Create a variable `found` outside loop if found.
    - On iteration, first check `found`

      - If found, return object without processing
      - If not, go to next level using recursion.
    - Return the new filtered value.

---

To check if object exists in sub-tree, you can use following:

```
new RegExp(`"id":("?)${id}("?),`)
```

---

Working sample:

```js
const explorer = {"id":"1","name":"root","isFolder":"true","items":[{"id":"2","name":"public","isFolder":"true","items":[{"id":"3","name":"index.html","isFolder":false,"items":[]},{"id":"4","name":"style.css","isFolder":false,"items":[]}]},{"id":"5","name":"app.js","isFolder":false,"items":[]},{"id":"6","name":"src","isFolder":true,"items":[{"id":"7","name":"components","isFolder":true,"items":[{"id":"8","name":"Folder.js","isFolder":false,"items":[]}]}]}]}

const deleteExplorer = (obj, id) => {
  const regex = new RegExp(`"id":("?)${id}("?),`)
  const exists = regex.test(JSON.stringify(obj));
  let found = false;
  if (exists) {
    if (obj.id === id) return null;
    obj.items = obj.items.reduce((acc, item) => {
      let retValue = item
      if (!found) {
        retValue = deleteExplorer(item, id)
        if (!retValue) {
          found = true;
        }
      }
      acc.push(retValue)
      return acc
    }, [])
  }
  return obj
}

console.log(deleteExplorer(explorer, "3"))
```